# How to include global module to spec files in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, docker, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm facing a problem where in my development setup (gitlab-runner with docker executing karma-runner for tests) browser of my choice Phantom.js starts spitting animation errors (more informations here: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/14210). Since puppeteer has approximately ~280mb I don't want to replace phantomjs with it on runner pipelines. Is there a way to include global module before each spec file is executed? That way I can stop animations by importing NoopAnimationsModule.

Export from gitlab-runner pipeline.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) LayoutComponent should create FAILED
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'getAnimationStyle(element, '').trim') in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js (line 5211)
    applyKeyframeAnimation@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:5211:46
    apply@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:5170:31
    init@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:5334:27
    play@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:5340:18
    play@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:4858:95
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:4638:24
    <Jasmine>
    _flushAnimations@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:4631:28
    flush@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:4280:48
    flush@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:5128:37
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:135595:35
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11874:31
    onInvoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:208197:45
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11873:60
    run@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11633:49
    runOutsideAngular@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:78855:31
    end@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:135593:41
    end@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:85716:30
    detectChanges@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:83201:23
    _tick@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:86262:45
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:86276:54
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11874:31
    onInvoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:208197:45
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11873:60
    onInvoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:78896:39
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11873:60
    run@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11633:49
    run@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:78810:31
    detectChanges@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:86276:28
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:6430:30
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11874:31
    onInvoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:208197:45
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11873:60
    run@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11633:49
    runInTestZone@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:208418:37
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:208433:33
    <Jasmine>
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:208734:35
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11874:31
    onInvoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:208197:45
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11873:60
    run@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11633:49
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:208733:32
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:208565:45
    invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11906:36
    runTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11678:57
    invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11981:41
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:11970:52
    timer@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:13764:34
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 5 of 10 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 2.575 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 6 of 10 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 3.274 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 7 of 10 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 4.01 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 8 of 10 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 4.069 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 9 of 10 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 4.112 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 10 of 10 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 4.457 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 10 of 10 (1 FAILED) (4.896 secs / 4.457 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 9 SUCCESS
```

How I can fix this problem without switching to puppeteer since this will change image size of the runner significantly and execution time would be multiple times slower. Is there any way to Include global module to be imported before testbed for specific .spec file ?

Comment: Simply add it to your test bed ?

Comment: Add it to test bed in every component and remember to add it everytime? Sure but I wonder if exists a simpler method. I'm thinking about projects that already has like 100 components that would be painfull.

Comment: Yeah well that's the basics of testing : if you have 100 components that need it, and 10 that don't need it, will you import it anyway in the 10 other components ? You can still create a function that creates a basic testbed, but that's all you can do, as the testbed is being created at every test (ran in a `beforeEach`) to avoid side effects between isolated tests.

Comment: Function would resolve this problem. Maybe it is not the best solution but it would work. You right about testing basics. Thanks for the comment appreciate it!